# Font changes during the runtime in WPF app

Tags: wpf, fonts

I'm using a non English (Hebrew) font in a WPF application. The font was embedded in the project by expression blend.

In the designer I see the font correctly, but during the run time **part** of the letters are being changed to different font style.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Are the design and runtime environment on the same machine ?
If not, check for installed fonts.
If it's on the same machine, then maybe check if some localization happens on during runtime.